# How do I prove that $f(x)=\frac{1}{1+x^2}$ is continuous on $\mathbb{R}$?

Tags: real-analysis

$f(x)=\frac{1}{1+x^2}$ is continuous on $\mathbb{R}$ if for all $\varepsilon>0$ there is a $\delta>0$ such that for all $a\in\mathbb{R}$, $$\left|\frac{1}{1+x^2}-\frac{1}{1+a^2}\right|<\varepsilon\text{ when }\left|x-a\right|<\delta\text{.}$$

All I can manage from this is that $\left|\frac{1}{1+x^2}-\frac{1}{1+a^2}\right|=\left|\frac{(a-x)(a+x)}{(1+x^2)(1+a^2)}\right|$ so I'm thinking I need to find a way to factor $(a+x)$ out of the numerator so I'm left with $|x-a|<\delta$. Don't know how to proceed. Any tips?

Comment: The composition preserves continuity.

Answer (score 11, accepted):

Note that 
$\left|\frac{(a-x)(a+x)}{(1+x^2)(1+a^2)}\right| \le | (a-x)(a+x)|$.

Then choose $\delta$ so that at worst, $\delta \le 1$, then $|a+x| \le 2|a|+1$.

**Addendum**: The idea is to show that for any $a$ and for any $\epsilon>0$ that we can find a $\delta>0$ such that if $|x-a|< \delta$, then $|f(x)-f(a)| < \epsilon$.

So, pick some arbitrary $a$ and $\epsilon>0$. We can decide up front that we will pick a $\delta \le 1$, as this will simplify our life. The above estimate shows that we have
$|f(x)-f(a)| \le (2|a|+1) |x-a|$.

Now we just need to pick another bound on $\delta$ so that if $|x-a|< \delta$, then $|f(x)-f(a)| < \epsilon$.

From the last estimate, we want to pick a $\delta$ so that 
$(2|a|+1) \delta < \epsilon$, so lets try that. Choose $\delta = {1 \over 2}\min(1, { \epsilon \over (2|a|+1)})$. (I am picking the ${1 \over 2}$ just to get the $<$ rather than a $\le$, any number $<1$ will do.)

Then we have
$|f(x)-f(a)| \le (2|a|+1) |x-a| \le (2|a|+1) \delta \le {1 \over 2} \epsilon < \epsilon$.

Comment: Sorry, I'm still struggling with analysis. I understand that $\left|\frac{(a-x)(a+x)}{(1+x^2)(1+a^2)}\right|\leq\left|(a-x)(a+x)\right|$, but the way I understand solving these types of problems, my next step from there would be to say that $\left|x-a\right|<\frac{\varepsilon}{|x+a|}=\delta$. But I wouldn't know how to proceed from there. I don't quite understand your solution.

Comment: I added some text that might help.

Answer (score 3):

It's actually uniformly continuous, since it is $1/2$-Lipschitz, for $|f'(x)|\leqslant 1/2$ over all $\Bbb R$. More generally if $f:\Bbb R\to\Bbb R$ is continous and $f\to 0$ as $|x|\to\infty$, $f$ is uniformly continuous.

Comment: this is so silly

Answer (score 2):

$x \mapsto 1+x^2$ is continuous on $\mathbb{R}$ and $y\mapsto1/y$ is continuous on $(0, \infty)$.  Then the result follows as long as you can show that if $f: X\to Y$ and $g: Y\to \mathbb{R}$ are functions, $f$ is continuous at $x_0$ and $g$ is continuous at $f(x_0)$. Then the composition is continuous at $x_0$, i.e., $(g \circ f)(x_0)$ is continuous.

Proof (1): (We use $\varepsilon-\delta$ definition)

Let $y_0 =f (x_0)$. Given $\varepsilon>0$ there is a $\delta _1>0$ such that $|g(y)-g(y_0)|< \varepsilon$ whenever  $|y-y_0|< \delta_1$. Let us pick this $\delta_1$. So by definition of continuity there is $\delta>0$ such that $|f(x)-f(x_0)|<\delta_1$ whenever $|x-x_0|<\delta$. In particular  for  all the $f(x)$ such that $x\in (x_0-\delta, x_0+\delta)$, $f(x)\in (y_0-\delta_1,y_0+\delta_1)$ and so $|g(f(x))-g(f(x_0))|< \varepsilon$, i.e., $|(g \circ f )(x)-(g \circ f )(x_0)|$ whenever $|x-x_0|< \delta$.

Proof (2): (We use sequences)

Given $(x_n)_{n=0}^\infty$ such that $x_n \in X$ and $x_n \to x_0$, $f(x_n) \to f(x_0)= y_0 $ since $f$ is continuous at $x_0$. Similarly $g$ is continuous at $y_0$ and $f(x_n)\to y_0$ so $g(f(x_n)) \to g(y_0)=(g \circ f)(x_0)$. Since $x_n$ was arbitrary  then for all sequences $a_n \to x_0$ it follows that $(g\circ f)(a_n) \to (g \circ f)(x_0)$. Hence $g \circ f$ is continuous at $x_0$